# Stored Child transform variable does not update

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a unity game where I have a bunch of objects that are children of the player object. So when the player runs around, the children objects also run around relative to the player.

At the beginning of the game, I have a transform variable that stores the transform of one of the child objects, then i use that transform variable for the rest of the game to have the enemies use that to chase the children.

Transform  childTransform=GameObject.Find("Parent").FindInChildren("child_1").transform;

But it seems this variable that points to the child transform, doesnt get updated to the current value when the parent moves. It just stays in the original position when i assigned it, so the enemy dont follow the current position, it just stays at the original position.

Maybe my code is wrong?

I thought it would get updated automatically to be the world space value of the child relative to the parent.

Anybody knows why? Do I have to constantly look up the child and reassign the variable each Update()? Isnt that a waste of CPU time?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Transform.position or Transform.localPosition?

Comment: As itchee says. Either you check localPosition or your parent object doesn't move. Also you could detached the child_1 object seting child_1.transform.parent = null;